# How to assign zones to one list based on the contents of another list in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am new to RStudio and attempting to write some code to help sort through a massive dataset I am analyzing. I have a list of 20 data frames ("A") that each look a little like this:

`A[["L048"]]`:

```
    PointID  MaxLoad `Load@1` `StructuralStiffness@1` ZoneID
       <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>                   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1       1  0.0976   0.0689                  0.0689      0
 2       2  0.0351   0.0247                  0.0247      0
 3       3  0.0332   0.0223                  0.0223      0
 4       4  0.0554   0.0395                  0.0395      0
```

I also have another respective list of 20 data frames ("list_all_zones") with Zone IDs:

```
list_all_zones[["L048"]]

    Z1    Z2    Z3    Z4    Z5    Z6    Z7    Z8    Z9   Z10
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     9    10    11    42    23    24    25    26    31    47
2     1     2     3     4    44    16    17    18    34    36
3     5     6     7     8    19    20    21    22    30    32
4    43    13    14    15    45    27    28    29    46    35
```

I would like to sort through both the lists, identify the PointID's respective zone, and assign the zone ID to get an outcome such as this:

```
       PointID   MaxLoad `Load@1` `StructuralStiffness@1`   ZoneID
          <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>                   <dbl>    <dbl>
     1       1  0.0976   0.0689                  0.0689      Z1
     2       2  0.0351   0.0247                  0.0247      Z2
     3       3  0.0332   0.0223                  0.0223      Z3
     4       4  0.0554   0.0395                  0.0395      Z4
```

Comment: How does the data tie together? What about `PointID=1` clearly demonstrates that it should be taken from `list_all_zones[["L048"]]$Z1`?

Comment: What if there are more matches?